# How render a route relevant subheader with meteor blaze?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, routes, meteor-blaze

The end result of all of what I am about to go over is the subheader is not rendering on screen like i want it to.

Currently there is a mongo collection subheader with a `category` field and a `texth` field.

```
Subheader = new Mongo.Collection('subheader');

Meteor.methods({
  subheaderInsert: function(subheaderIdAttributes) {
  check(String);
  check(subheaderIdAttributes, {
    texth: String,
    category: String
  });
  var subheaderId = _.extend(postAttributes, {
    submitted: new Date()
  });
  var subheaderId = SubheaderId.insert(subheader);
    return {
    _id: subheaderId
  };
}
});
```

There is a route that subscribes to the subheader and other page data.

```
Router.route('/', {
  name: 'home',
    controller: MissionstatementpostController,
    waitOn:function () {
  return Meteor.subscribe('subheader', 'home');
  }
});
```

The publish function appears to work fine.

```
Meteor.publish('subheader', function(cat) {
  return Subheader.find({category: cat});
});
```

The correct doc from the mongodb collection is reaching the client. this can be seen by

```
Subheader.findOne(); output Object {_id: "NPo5cwqgjYY6i9rtx", texth: "ex text", category: "home"}
```

**The problem starts here**

The template loaded by the Controller in this case `MissionstatementpostController` is `postlist`

```
<template name="postsList">
    <div class="posts page">
          {{> subheader}}
    <div class="wrapper">
      {{#each posts}}
        {{> postItem}}
      {{/each}}
    </div> 
    {{#if nextPath}}
      <a class="load-more" href="{{nextPath}}">Load more</a>
    {{else}}
      {{#unless ready}}
        {{> spinner}}
      {{/unless}}
    {{/if}}
  </div>
</template>
```

Here is the subheader template

```
<template name="subheader">
    <div class="container">
        <p>{{{texth}}}</p>
    </div>
</template>
```

**So what did I mess-up?**

thanks

Answer (score 0):

you must create a template helper for your subheader template. To return just the `texth` field, the helper will be like this.

```
Template.subheader.helpers({
  texth: function() {
    var sh = Subheader.findOne();
    return sh && sh.texth;
  }
});
```

You can return the whole document and use the `#with` helper inside the template.

```
Template.subheader.helpers({
  subh: function() {
    return Subheader.findOne();
  }
});

<template name="subheader">
    {{#with subh}}
    <div class="container">
        <p>{{{texth}}}</p>
    </div>
    {{/with}}
</template>
```

You can find more info about template helpers on [Meteor Docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_helpers).